# Rows manipulation on an array

Tags: c++, matrix, rows

I have to do this exercise :

> Write a C + + function that, given an array with two
>   NxN size of integers, returns true if the rows to have all the
>   same elements (even in different locations), and false otherwise.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 5;


bool fool ( const int a [N][N])
{
    int x,y = 0;
    int j=0;
    int i=0;

    bool check[N] = {false};
    bool verify = false;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    {

       check[i] = false;

    }

       while(j<N && !verify )
       {

         if(a[x][i]==a[y][j] && !check[j] )
         {

            check[j]=true;
            verify=true;
         }

         j++;

       }

       return verify;

}


int main ()
{


    const int a[N][N] = {{1,3,5,6,7},
                         {5,6,7,1,3},
                         {1,6,5,3,7},
                         {6,1,3,5,7},
                         {6,5,1,7,3}};




    if ( fool(a))
    {

           cout << " in all rows there are the same elements";

    }


    else
    {

           cout << " wrong, . ";

    }

    return 0;


}
```

But the program crashes. How can I fix it?

Comment: It crashes? Some more information would probably be helpful.

Comment: `j` is never initialized by the way.

Comment: It crashes where exactly? Any specific errors you're getting? Solving such problems starts with localizing them... And are you sure that's your actual code? What are you compiling it with?

Comment: `bool check[N] = false;` - what the heck is this syntax? Also, I checked the code and it gives five errors and three warnings - how can it crash if it doesn't even compile (unless you use some insane compiler...).

Comment: ok i tried to inizialize j but it gives me an error in "bool check" , belonging syntax errors, the algorithm is correct?

Comment: @Griwes yes, i edited the code and now it gives me this warning and errors , before it crashes.

Comment: `x` and `j` and not initialized to 0, `i` is being handled wrongly, too.

Comment: @Bart i use codeblocks on GNU/Linux , compiler say that the array must be inizialized with a brace-enclosed initializer.

Comment: @osiris_0100, so it doesn't *crash*, but is just plainly wrong. Go re-read your C++ book and then come back, after seeing what the heck have you created.

Comment: @Griwes i fix the syntax errors, but now the code crash and do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while( int j<N && !verify )
```

Don't declare `j` inside the loop, it should be declared outside. I'm surprised this even compiles (it doesn't compile in Visual Studio C++).

Answer (score 2):

Forget about the crash for a moment. There are many compiler errors.

1)

```
bool check[N] = false;
```

should be:

```
bool check[N] = {false}
```

2) You declare `i` inside the `for` loop which makes its scope limited to the loop

```
for ( int i=0; i<N; i++)
```

but you access it in the `if` statement outside the loop. That won't work. To fix this declare the variable outside the loop.

3) The following is incorrect:

```
while( int j<N && !verify )
```

To fix this declare the variable `j` outside the loop.

**Possible cause of crash:**

The variables `j`, `x` and `y` are not initialized, it has garbage in it.

Comment: ok , with this fixes, compiler work and terminate without errors, but the program crashes and do nothing. ( sorry for my bad english)

Comment: i tried to initialize j,x and y out the for and while loops but it crash anyway